# Can I transit at WAW (Poland) with separate tickets, without 90 days on my passport for Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, transit, passports, check-in, warsaw

I'm a Japanese national who does not need Visa for entering Schengen area.

I'm now in Ukraine, but I found I need to renew my passport as it is expiring.

So I bought a flight ticket, from WAW (Warsaw) - NRT (Tokyo), departing on July 26th 2018.

As my passport's expiration date is coming soon, October 1st 2018, in most countries, the final date to enter is July 1st, 2018.

It seemed OK, but I found I can not enter Poland with my passport due to the validity date.

I planned to go to WAW by airplane, from Kiev. Or maybe by bus.

Anyway, is it possible to receive baggage and check-in without entering Poland? As I remember usual baggage claim is after immigration control.

Is it possible to enter by car if I show ticket?

Answer (score 1):

I think you *could* avoid checking-in baggage to Warsaw (which you won't be able to reclaim without entering), and check-in online for the second leg of your trip and just transit airside.

However, there's a fat chance that you won't be allowed to board plane in Kiev, since you're not allowed to enter destination country.

Why don't you renew your passport using Japanese embassy consular services? They should do exactly that.

Comment: Thank you much.
It seems not possible to check-in, with separate ticket, at WAW, in usual way.
Any advice or experience?

Renewing passport at embassy in foreign country is not easy to prepare documents for it.
even much easier to go back and apply

Comment: @satio2000 With web check in, you should be able to print boarding pass at home, go directly to the gate at WAW for boarding towards NRT.

Comment: Thank you for help. anyway, it was not possible to check-in online, because I had luggage to check-in.
and not all airlines support online check in.
anyway, Thank you.